# Ubuntu - Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enable (while trying to upgrade my Nodejs version)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, upgrade, uefi, nodejs

've been trying to upgrade my nodejs version cause when I ran the command to install it, automatically installed v4.2.6 and i've been playing around to try to fix this and the output is always the same: UEFI secure boot is enabled, and apparently is something about the dpkg.

Comment: Nodejs 4.2.6 is the correct version for Ubuntu 16.04, which is two years old. What exactly are you trying to install, and how?

Comment: Im trying to upgrade the version to the current one and apparently the npm isn't working either. And every time i run the "sudo apt install npm" saids thatdpkg was interrupted , you must manually run " sudo dpkg --configure -a" and hen i run that command , throws the UEFI error

Comment: What do you mean by "the current one"? Also, please edit your question to show a complete terminal session with what you are inputting and the complete outputs, including full errors.

Comment: "the current one" -> the current version of node instead the v4.2.6 , anyway thanks a lot, i followed the steps the command line gave me, I change the super user password and reboot the system, then a window pops-up asking for the new password i reboot the pc again and , just like magic I was able to install nodejs newest version. but thank you anyway!